# MSVC binds non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue/temporary

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, language-lawyer, c++98

MSVC lets you bind non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue/temporary. I have tested VS2008, VS2010, VS2012, VS2015, and multiple VS2017 all of them fine with the code below while Clang 3-8 and GCC 4-9 gives an error.

```
struct dummy {};
template <typename T> void foo(T&) {}
template <typename T> T bar() { return T(); }

int main()
{
    //int& i = 1;       // 1. Fails as expected on all compilers
    //foo(1);           // 2. Fails as expected on all compilers
    //foo(bar<int>());  // 3. Fails as expected on all compilers
    dummy& d = dummy(); // 4. OK on MSVC
    foo(dummy());       // 5. OK on MSVC
    foo(bar<dummy>());  // 6. OK on MSVC
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1u5EVD

Are not all those cases forbidden in
[[dcl.init.ref]/5.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.2)? Am I missing something? Somebody should have noticed that MSVC violates the basics of the standard for decades.

Comment: It's a well known fact. MSVC allows it as an extension. Build with [/Za](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions) or, in recent versions, [/Zc:referenceBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-referencebinding-enforce-reference-binding-rules) to get standard-conforming behavior.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik thanks, and it emits warning with /W4 (but not with /W3 I tested on), please place your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am with @Igor MSVC allows a lot of shite, may be to stay compatible with pre-standardized code already written.

Comment: Use /permissive- even, for maximum C++ conformance. In this case, the errors are properly reported.